# Aggregation Binding with nested JSON Arrays in SAPUI5 XML View

Tags: arrays, json, xml, sapui5

i am trying to do Aggregation Binding with data from nested Arrays in my JSON Model:
here is my "Menus.json" Model:

```
"days": {
    "monday": {
        "menus": [{
            "menu": "Spaghetti mit Rinder-Bolognese oder VEGATARISCH mit TomatenBasilikumsoße und Parmesan",
            "price": "3.90",
            "price2": "2.90",
            "title": "Menü 1"
        }, {
            "menu": "Schweinerückensteak frisch aus der Pfanne Maisgemüse mit Ofenpaprika und Blattpetersilie Kartoffel Gnocchi im Kürbissud grüne Pfeffer-Butter mit Basilikum",
            "price": "4.40",
            "price2": "3.40",
            "title": "Menü 2"
        }, {
            "menu": "Tilapia aus dem Ofen mit Kokos-Zitronengras Sauce 2,70 € Chinakohl, Karotten, Champignons und Erbsen Jasmin Duftreis",
            "price": "4.80",
            "price2": "3.50",
            "title": "Live Cooking"
        }, {
            "menu": "VEGETARISCH Kokos Paprikasuppe",
            "price": "1.20",
            "price2": "Suppenschale: 3.50",
            "title": "Suppe"
        }, {
            "menu": "Blumenkohl-Lauch Bratling mit Soja-Kerbeldip",
            "price": "2.50",
            "price2": "",
            "title": "Veganer Bratling"
        }]
    }, 
    "tuesday": {
        "menus": [{...}]
    }, 
    "wednesday": {
        "menus": [{...}]
    }, 
    "thursday": {
        "menus": [{...}]
    }, 
    "friday": {
        "menus": [{...}]
    }
}
```

}
i want to bind for example "monday" to my table like this

```
<Table id="nordMenuTable" inset="false" items="{Menus>/monday/menus}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true"/>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="WithoutHeader"><ObjectIdentifier title="{i18n>NordColumn1}"/></Column>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline"><ObjectIdentifier title="{i18n>NordColumn3}"/></Column>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" hAlign="End"><ObjectIdentifier title="{i18n>NordColumn2}"/></Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{Menus>title}"/>
                            <Text text="{Menus>menu}"/>
                            <Text text="{Menus>price2}"/>
                            <Text text="{Menus>price}"/>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
```

Please help me out with a binding syntax for JSON Files with nested arrays. I know that things would work, if i would have a single JSON Model with only the data in the nested array, but i need my JSON File like this with all menus related to the certain days.

Comment: Will you always bing "monday" to the table or was just an example? Also, are you able to change the JSON structure? Assuming you need all menus from all weekdays in the table it's not even possible with factory functions. Like that you would need to manually add items on the table

Comment: Hi @fabiopagoti , thank you for noting that. Yeah it was just an example to bind only monday. Do you have an idea or an example how to deal with all 5 days dynamically? and change the table binding by pressing a button or something like that

Comment: Hello! That is what I mean: with many arrays spread in a big JSON, you won't be able to use data binding. Using the JSON schema you have, the only option would be to dynamically add rows by using add/insert methods of the sap.m.Table class. You don't necessarily need a button to explicitly do it. If you have control over the JSON structure, I suggest to change it in order to have the many benefits of data binding. If you don't, there is no other good alternative in IMO. What would you like to do? Change the JSON format or not use data binding?

Comment: @fabiopagoti then i would like to change the JSON format, but i only want to display the menu of one day. So for example if i would have 5 buttons at a footer for each day i only want the certain menu displayed, that is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json model should be something like:

```
{
    "days": {
        "monday": {
            "menus": [{

            }]
        },
        "tuesday": {
            "menus": [{

            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Your `items` aggregation shoud be `items="{Menus>/days/monday/menus}"`
and for `ColumnListItem`  paths `{Menus>menu}` since they are relative paths

Comment: had some mistakes in my example above sorry for that, but i also tried it exactly the way you did and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: In the ColumnListItem paths you have to remove the slash since they are relative paths.
How do you declare your jsonModel?

Answer (score -1):

[View SS][Your JSON is incorrect firstly correct your Json.
Then In View Bind like this, Here my model name is device.
JSON:

````
    {
    "days": [{
        "monday": {
            "menus": [{
                "menu": "Spaghetti mit Rinder-Bolognese oder VEGATARISCH mit TomatenBasilikumsoße und Parmesan",
                "price": "3.90",
                "price2": "2.90",
                "title": "Menü 1"
            }, {
                "menu": "Schweinerückensteak frisch aus der Pfanne Maisgemüse mit Ofenpaprika und Blattpetersilie Kartoffel Gnocchi im Kürbissud grüne Pfeffer-Butter mit Basilikum",
                "price": "4.40",
                "price2": "3.40",
                "title": "Menü 2"
            }, {
                "menu": "Tilapia aus dem Ofen mit Kokos-Zitronengras Sauce 2,70 € Chinakohl, Karotten, Champignons und Erbsen Jasmin Duftreis",
                "price": "4.80",
                "price2": "3.50",
                "title": "Live Cooking"
            }, {
                "menu": "VEGETARISCH Kokos Paprikasuppe",
                "price": "1.20",
                "price2": "Suppenschale: 3.50",
                "title": "Suppe"
            }, {
                "menu": "Blumenkohl-Lauch Bratling mit Soja-Kerbeldip",
                "price": "2.50",
                "price2": "",
                "title": "Veganer Bratling"
            }]
        }
    }]
};

```
    <Table id="nordMenuTable" inset="false" items="{path : 'device>/days/0/monday/menus'}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true"/>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="WithoutHeader"><ObjectIdentifier title="Hello1"/></Column>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline"><ObjectIdentifier title="{i18n>NordColumn3}"/></Column>
                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" hAlign="End"><ObjectIdentifier title="Hello2"/></Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>

                            <cells>
                              <Text text="{device>title}"/>
                              <Text text="{device>price2}"/>
                               <Text text="{device>price}"/>

                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej022.png
````